# How to open new windows in each 5 sec, using server side code?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using Thread.sleep(5000) and then using Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, key, script) function to open a new window.
I am getting 5 new windows but not in each 5 sec, they all appear together, after 25 sec. Here is my sample code:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    string openPage = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>";
    openPage += "window.open('http://www.winpossible.com','mywindow" + i + "','width=600,height=800,toolbar=no,location=Yes,directories=no,status=no,resizable=yes');";                       openPage += "</script>";

    // Open a new window if there is a new teacher-Student pair comes.
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "sample" + i, openPage);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your insightful and elegant solutions to this problem! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

As your using server-side code, it runs on the server, and all the delays goes **before** you send the HTML page to the client.

When the HTML page gets to the client, it shows the 5 pages at once.

What you must do is open the pages using javascript.

Look at this example:

http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/delayed-popup.html

It opens a new window after a delay, you can use the same concept for opening your five windows.

**Doing that from server side code is not possible.**